# A infinity structure on Yoneda Ext group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology, a-infinity-algebras

I am currently trying to control an $A_\infty$-algebra of the form $\mathrm{Ext}_X(F\oplus F'[2n-2],F\oplus F'[2n-2])$ where $X$ is a nice enough scheme and $F,F'$ are sheaves that are NOT locally free. Now as this $A_\infty$-structure is quite elusive I was hoping I could control it on the Yoneda-$\mathrm{Ext}$ level, in particular as I feel more comfortable with homological algebra. So I wanted to ask if anyone knows about such a construction and maybe even point me to a paper on it, I sadly could not find one yet.